# How to use ubuntu command line to find a holiday?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, command

How to use ubuntu command to find the date of Mother's Day (Second Sunday of May) in 2017?

Since -v doesn't work on ubuntu, it works on Mac.

Comment: for which country?

Comment: Mother's day is celebrated on different dates in different countries (see, e.g., [the wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother%27s_Day#Dates_around_the_world)). What day exactly are you trying to find?

Comment: Second Sunday of May

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say its usually the second sunday of may :

```
fhenri@machine:~$ date -v1d -v5m -v+1y -v+2w -v-sun
Dim 14 mai 2017 22:56:28 CEST
```

you should look at `man date` to get more examples and to find out if you need another particular sunday or fix day

I was running on my macos (freeBSD based) and did not realized `date` was not uniform across *nix system.

on ubuntu, it revealed a bit more difficult but here how I would go

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ firstofmay=$(date -d '05/01/2017')
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ firstsunday=$(date -d "$firstofmay" '+%Y-%m')-$(( 8 - $(date -d "$firstofmay" '+%u') ))
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ secondsunday=$(date -d "$firstsunday + 1 week" '+%Y-%m-%d')
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ echo $secondsunday
2017-05-14
```

1. first I initialize the 1st of may as my base date
2. then I get a format of the first sunday from this month: day are 7 based and `$(date -d "$firstofmonth" '+%u')` will be the day number of the first of may (i.e.: monday is 1); this gives a format such as YYYY-MM-dd
3. adding 1 week to this date I have previously gives the correct date - adjust the formatting if you want it different

Comment: what is the meaing of -v here, in my man date, there is only -d, -f, -r, -R, -s, -u, --help.  So, 1d means 1 day, 5m --> may, +1y --> next year, +2w --> second week. But i can't use -v here. I am using ubuntu.

Comment: right, you mention unix in your system and tag it unix, making the answer for date command of ubuntu